# How to convert request query to correct MongoDB query string?

Tags: mongodb, express

The request (req.query) I got has this format:

```
{ duration: { gte: '5' }, difficulty: 'easy' }
```

To make it work in MongoDB, the final result should be as below

```
{ duration: { $gte: 5 }, difficulty: 'easy' }
```

This is the code I'm using

```
const queryObj = { ...req.query };
let queryStr = JSON.stringify(queryObj);
queryStr = queryStr.replace(/\b(gte|lte|gt|lt)\b/g, (match) => `$${match}`);
```

However, the output is `{ duration: { '$gte': '5' }, difficulty: 'easy' }`
so it didn't work.

```
{ duration: { $gte: 5 }, difficulty: 'easy' } : return every matched records
{ duration: { '$gte': '5' }, difficulty: 'easy' }: return 0 record.
```

My question is: How can i remove the '' sign so it can be used for query string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex approach won't work with converting numbers as a `regex` is binding you to  stay with `string`. You're going to have to iterate over the entire object and check each key.

Here is a very simple recursive function that achieves this:

```
let finalObject = { duration: { gte: '5' }, difficulty: 'easy' }

function recursivelySearchObject(object) {
    if (typeof object === "string") {
        if (/^\d+$/.test(object)) {
            return parseInt(object)
        } else {
            return object
        }
    } else {
        Object.keys(object).forEach((key) => {
            object[key] = recursivelySearchObject(object[key]);
        });
        return object
    }
}

recursivelySearchObject(finalObject);
```

You can skip the recursive aspect if the object will always be "shallow" and just check to a certain depth using a for loop instead.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! By the way, I'm still puzzled at why the query string with ' ' didn't work. Is this expected?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `query string` but Mongo expects a number for `$gte`. it doesn't validate and sanitize input.

Comment: I edited my question with a bit more information. Basically, I tried 2 different query string in Mongo DB Atlas filter.

Comment: So  the problem is again with the `5`, Mongo can receive key names without `"` or `'` around them as-long as you're not using the dot notation, but as i mentioned `$gte` expects a number in this context. otherwise is trying to compare strings and your field is not `string` type.

Comment: Ah I see!! Thank you, Tom.